A property of Schur Complement
I would like to show that for $R_2$ positive definite matrix, $R_2>0$, that:
$$R_1-R_{12}R_2^{-1}R_{12}^T\ge 0 \Leftrightarrow \left[\begin{array}{cc}
R_1 & R_{12}\\
R_{12}^T & R_2\end{array}\right]\ge 0$$
How to show this?
Thanks!

The block matrix is congruent to the direct sum of $R_2$ and its Schur complement.

@MathematicalPhysicist Note that askers are expected to provide context on this site. Please [edit] your question to tell us what your thoughts are and what you've tried so far.

@MathematicalPhysicist Also, have you learned about matrix congruence?

As a hint, you should consider the product $PRP^T$, where $R$ denotes your block-matrix and
$$
P = \pmatrix{I & -R_{12}R_2^{-1}\ 0 & I}.
$$
